# selecting rows with id from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's call this table `terms_relation`:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
| term_id | taxonomy | description | created_at | updated_at |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|       1 | categ    | non         | 3434343434 |   34343433 |  |
|       2 | categ    | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|       3 | tag      | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|       4 | tag      | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

And this is table `terms`:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id |    name     |    slug     |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | hello       | hello       |
|  2 | how are you | how-are-you |
|  3 | tutorial    | tutorial    |
|  4 | the end     | the-end     |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

How Do I select all rows in table `terms` and table `terms_relation` where it's taxonomy in table `terms_relation` is `categ`? Will I need two queries for this or I could use a `join` statement?

Comment: Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: Yes, learn about SQL joins. Learn at http://sqlzoo.net/ and http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Try this (subquery):

```
SELECT * FROM terms WHERE id IN 
   (SELECT term_id FROM terms_relation WHERE taxonomy = "categ")
```

Or you can try this (JOIN):

```
SELECT t.* FROM terms AS t 
   INNER JOIN terms_relation AS tr 
   ON t.id = tr.term_id AND tr.taxonomy = "categ"
```

If you want to receive all fields from two tables:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.slug, tr.description, tr.created_at, tr.updated_at 
  FROM terms AS t 
   INNER JOIN terms_relation AS tr 
   ON t.id = tr.term_id AND tr.taxonomy = "categ"
```

Comment: Updated an answer. It's simple, just add what you need right after SELECT

Comment: amazing, you two guys are correct. It's hard to choose, thank you!

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that JOIN is an order of magnitude more efficient than the subquery method.

Comment: Just to clear doubts, what is the advantage of one method over other? Should I go with Joins or a subquery?

Answer (score 28):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM terms
WHERE id IN (SELECT term_id FROM terms_relation WHERE taxonomy='categ');
```

and if you need to show all columns from both tables:

```
SELECT t.*, tr.*
FROM terms t, terms_relation tr
WHERE t.id = tr.term_id
AND tr.taxonomy='categ'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT terms.*
FROM terms JOIN terms_relation ON id=term_id
WHERE taxonomy='categ'
```