# How to select records from MySQL filtering by a file with listed ids?

Tags: mysql

I have a file, which contains ids, separated by '\n'. The file has about 100 000 lines. I want to know the best (the fastest) way to extract records from a MySQL table, where ids are in the file. I can't use the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` IN (...);
```

because the request line is too long in my case.

Thanks!

Comment: I would use a programming language to parse the file, query all records from the table, and compare the results. Alternatively, walk through each record, whatever the memory dimensions we are talking about here... although you *might* be able to do something clever loading the file into a table, and then "fusing" the two tables, don't know

Comment: Thanks, but the table contains about 100 mln records. It's not a good idea to select all data. I suppose, there's a standard way to select by a file with listed ids.

Comment: Argh, yeah of course, this is easy using a subquery. But you have to have the file's contents in a table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562915/selecting-rows-with-id-from-another-table

Comment: Thanks, but it's not convenient. It's better to use 100 thousands queries instead like:

    SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE `id` = '...';

Comment: I don't think a 100,000 records long `IN()` clause is going to be very performant, even if you get it to work. Getting the file's contents into a table would be as easy as `LOAD DATA INFILE`, no?

Comment: You can increase max_allowed_packet variable to be bigger then size of your query and then it should work - however performance will be poor I guess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335011/what-is-maximum-query-size-for-mysql

Comment: Thanks! As far as I see, there's no flexible and standard way to it. I decided to do 10 queries `SELECT ... IN ...` setting 10,000 ids for each query. It works pretty fast.