# mysql foreign key doesnt reflect to its references

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I would like to ask. How do I reference an image path from 'profiles' table to the 'users' table. The column from 'profiles' table would be 'image' while the column from 'users' table would be 'avatar'. Somehow every time I updated image on my profile, it won't reflect in my 'users' table even though I have referenced the column respectively from 'users' table to the 'profile' table.

**Users Schema**

[image]

**Profiles Schema**

[image]

Comment: Please post your schema

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular updated the question with schema.

Answer (score 1):

This is not what relationships in a database are for!

If the `image` field in the `profile` table is the avatar, then you need to first link `profile` and `users` tables together through a [foreign key](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and then you would query a user's profile through an [inner join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562915/selecting-rows-with-id-from-another-table) and thus get the corresponding `image` field.

Comment: Thank you for this, I actually have done this before but forgot how it is done actually. Will revisit my previous code.