# Selecting rows with id's from two other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's call this table `service_status`:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|service_id| output | created_at | updated_at   |   
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
|       1  |  non   | 3434343434 | 3434343332   |  
|       2  |  non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434   |  
|       3  |  non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434   |  
|       4  |  non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434   |  
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+
```

This is table `service`:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+---------+
|   host_id| service_id |output | created_at | updated_at |   
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+---------+
|      12  |  1         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343332 |  
|      23  |  2         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
|      34  |  3         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
|      45  |  4         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+---------+
```

And this one is called `hosts`:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+--------+----+
|   host_id| name           |output | created_at | updated_at |   
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+---------+---+
|      12  |  tesla         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343332 |  
|      23  |  microsoft     | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
|      34  |  apple         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
|      45  |  google        | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+---------+---+
```

The result I want a SELECT query to produce:

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|   name       | service_id |output | created_at | updated_at |   
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+
|   tesla      |  1         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343332 |  
|   microsoft  |  2         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
|   apple      |  3         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
|   goole      |  4         | non   | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+-------------+
```

How would I be able to achieve this type of query?

P.S.: I took inspiration from the following forum. Very similar to my question except they query from two tables: [selecting rows with id from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562915/selecting-rows-with-id-from-another-table)

Comment: Joining 3 tables is the same as joining 2 tables. Just add another `JOIN` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try to `inner join` the tables to get the result you want.

```
select h.name, ss.service_id, ss.output , ss.created_at , ss.updated_at from service_status ss 
INNER JOIN service s on ss.service_id = s.service_id
Inner Join hosts h on s.host_id = h.host_id
```